# How to call the other of two similar routes in an RSpec controller spec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

Rails 4.1.8  
 Rspec 3.4.4

Given 2 routes, I'm having trouble understanding how to call them.

Route a) `/data_services/add_comment/:id`   
Route b) `/data_services/:id/add_comment`

In services_controller_spec.rb

```
describe 'create comment' do
  let!(:service) { FactoryGirl.create(:service) }

  describe 'with valid comment' do
    it 'creates a new comment' do
      expect {
        post :add_comment, id: service.id
      }.to change(service.service_comments, :count).by(1)

      expect(response).to redirect_to(service_path(service))
    end
  end
end
```

I believe that with this code my test is referencing route a). How would I reference route b)?

Comment: It would be good to show the `describe ServicesController` block in your spec, and also to include the relevant routes from `routes.rb`. It's not clear to me whether the second route routes to anything. Is your goal to have the second route be the one to `ServicesController#add_comment`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call an action in an rspec-rails controller spec, you're not calling a route, you're calling the controller and action directly. The `describe` block that you pass the controller name to tells rspec-rails the class name, and the action name that you pass to the `post` or `get` call tells rspec-rails the method name. It just instantiates the controller class and calls the method directly.

But, when the action method is called, Rails does look up the route to that controller and action and use it for a couple of incidental reasons, such as constructing the URI in `request.env['PATH_INFO']`. The route that's used depends on what's in your routes file, of course.

So, to exercise a given route in a controller spec, call the controller and action that the route routes to.

Note that rspec-rails also has [routing specs](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/routing-specs), which are for directly testing what a route routes to.